# Ionic Utility Classes: Breakpoints not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework, frameworks, responsive, breakpoints

I'm trying to apply a padding depending on the screen width, so I'd assume to go with `class="ion-padding-top-{breakpoint}"` or `class="ion-padding-{breakpoint}-top"` similar to other applications of breakpoints. But this does not work and the documentation lacks any specific examples or rules to follow.

I'm referring to [this page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities) of the documentation.

There it says at the bottom of the page:

> The following breakpoint names are used in the utility classes listed above, where the class will apply when the width is met.

It's working flawlessly without the breakpoints. What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is the example of your assumptions in that documentation page?

Comment: They are talking about breakpoints in the **Element Placement** and **Element Display** sections on that page.